# Reorder Magento JavaScript Includes (addJs)

Tags: javascript, magento

I'll keep this simple.... on my product pages I need to remove the prototype.js file and replace it with the latest version of prototype. So far using local.xml I have successfully replaced it using this:

```
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/prototype.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype-new.js</script></action>
```

The issue is that now prototype is loaded below everything other includes which stops it working.

Is there a way of setting the order of a JavaScript include using local.xml without having to remove and add every single file again?

Answer (score 45):

You can use the params element, with "data-group" HTML attribute in it, Magento will put items with "params" set after any items with no "params" set. You can use local.xml in your theme to ensure the order of these elements (I recommend to let Magento add its standard files first):

```
<action method="addJs">
    <script>prototype/javascript0.js</script>
    <params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params>
    <!-- creates first group js002 -->
</action>
<action method="addJs">
    <script>prototype/javascript1.js</script>
    <params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params>
    <!-- appends to created group js002, after javascript0 -->
</action>
<action method="addJs">
    <script>prototype/javascript2.js</script>
    <params><![CDATA[data-group="js001"]]></params>
    <!-- creates first group js001 -->
</action>
<action method="addJs">
    <script>prototype/javascript3.js</script>
    <params><![CDATA[data-group="js001"]]></params>
    <!-- appends to created group js001, after javascript2 -->
</action>
<action method="addJs">
    <script>prototype/javascript4.js</script>
    <params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params>
    <!-- appends to created group js002, after javascript1 -->
</action>
<action method="addJs">
    <script>prototype/javascript5.js</script>
    <!-- no params supplied, will be rendered before any groups -->
</action>
```

The order in which elements with "params" set are rendered in only determined by the order in which actions are executed. Items are rendered grouped by the value of "params", so once group "js001" is defined by the first action (javascript2.js), successive actions with the same group name will append to that group, etc.

In the example above, the order of rendering will be:

- prototype/javascript5.js (no params, comes first)
- prototype/javascript0.js (first created params group "js002")
- prototype/javascript1.js (first created params group "js002")
- prototype/javascript4.js (first created params group "js002")
- prototype/javascript2.js (second created params group "js001")
- prototype/javascript3.js (second created params group "js001")

Items added using addItem addJs, addCss, etc, are threated in the same way, however they differ (and will be super-grouped accordingly) by type (see order below), with each group in super-groups internally ordered as explained above:

- js
- skin_js
- js_css
- skin_css

Comment: If you use the "Mygento JQuery Library and Plugins" module it works for all jQuery Plugins setting name-param to "last" or "[plugin name]"

Comment: Good solution, but only works within the same area - if you want to force an include to the top or bottom of ALL of them, you can't. At least, unless you put a `krsort($items)` in &_prepareStaticAndSkinElements of mage/page/block/html/head

Comment: is this possible with addItem method? I have js in my skin folder. I cannot get the right syntax if it is possible - any ideas?

Comment: @boobyWomack: Yes, the same syntax can be applied to addItem method, just add "params" as above as the last child element of "action"

Comment: @D.S. - just added this but it took no effect, although the name atributes were added to the Script tags. Format was:

 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/vendor/jquery.cycle2.min.js</name>
            <params><![CDATA[name="bxxx"]]></params>
            </action>

Comment: @boobyWomack - skin_js/skin_css and just js/css are threated differently, js/css have higher priority (Magento does output those before any skin_* item).

Comment: I don't believe this has any effect.  As @l-barker pointed out, it adds the parameter to the script tag but it does not sort using this parameter.  I stepped through the code and there's no sorting happening.  I think you got lucky in that your files happened to be included in the order you wanted, but there's no guarantee of that.  I don't know why they don't support "after=''" and "before=''" parameters like with layouts.  I'll keep searching for a solution.

Comment: @BrianVPS: it has effect (see code of Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::getCssJsHtml() method), but I'm afraid not exactly as I have originally explained. PHP keeps associative array elements in the same order as added (unless sorting is performed), but the code in getCssJsHtml groups items by the value in <params>. Please see new revised explanation, which should be more exact and complete. And thanks for you feedback!

Comment: Thank you! This solution works in 1.9.3.7 when ordering scripts is important.

Answer (score 1):

Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head $_data; holds the array of those items so I guess you can filter it for your own good. Default methods does not allow defining order of added items.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this post is pretty old but i stumbled on it while researching this problem, so i figured why not.

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but its working sufficiently well for us.

I basically created a new block in my `local.xml` like this:

    `<block type="core/template" name="prehead" template="page/html/prehead/main.phtml" />`

Then just modified my main layouts (1column.phtml and friends) to contain this:

    `<head>
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('prehead') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
    </head>`

In `main.phtml` I add my JS that I want to load first

`<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/require.js', array('_secure'=>true)); ?>'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/main.js', array('_secure'=>true)); ?>'></script>`

This is convenient for us as well because it still allows us to change the main.js depending on what page we are on by doing something like this in `local.xml`:

`<checkout_onestep_index translate="label">
        <label>One Step Checkout</label>
        <block type="core/template" name="prehead" template="page/html/prehead/checkout.phtml" />
     </checkout_onestep_index>`

Hope it helps someone who happens to stumble on this.

-Ken

Comment: yes this works but when we merge js than how can we add in merge js files from "prehead".

Answer (score 0):

Since **local.xml** is loaded at last by the magento system, so the xml mentioned there are merged at last. That may be the reason that your new prototype is loaded below other scripts.

Alternatively, you can override the **Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::getCssJsHtml()** method and play with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's my solution.
First copy app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\head.php to app\code\local\Mage\Page\Block\Html\head.php

Then add this function to the file :

```
public function replaceItem($type, $name, $replace)
{
    $newArray = array();

    foreach($this->_data['items'] as $key => $value) {
        if($key == $type.'/'.$name) {
            $newArray[$type . '/'. $replace] = array(
            'type'   => $type,
            'name'   => $replace,
            'params' => $value['params'],
            'if'     => $value['if'],
            'cond'   => $value['cond']);
        } else {
            $newArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    $this->_data['items'] = $newArray;
    return $this;
}
```

Now in your .XML layout file include a line like this :

```
<action method="replaceItem"><type>js</type><name>prototype/prototype.js</name><replace>onestepcheckout/prototype/prototype.js</replace></action>
```

The parameters are exactly as for removeItem BUT now the replace file will be injected into the list in the same place as the original file. It will also inherit the same param, if and cond values. Please use this code carefully as I've only just written and done basic tests on it!

Comment: the whole point of these workarounds is to avoid changing the core Magento files, as that is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Barny Shergold's solution is the most correct, but the comment about avoiding changing core files is correct. To have the best of both worlds, you can implement Barny's solution in a module that extends the Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head class like so:

Yourcompany/Layouthelper/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yourcompany_Layouthelper>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Yourcompany_Layouthelper>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_head>Yourcompany_Layouthelper_Block_Html_Head</html_head>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Yourcompany/Layouthelper/Block/Html/Head.php

```
class Yourcompany_Layouthelper_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head {

    public function replaceItem($type, $name, $replace) {
        $newArray = array();

        foreach($this->_data['items'] as $key => $value) {
            if($key == $type.'/'.$name) {
                $newArray[$type . '/'. $replace] = array(
                'type'   => $type,
                'name'   => $replace,
                'params' => $value['params'],
                'if'     => $value['if'],
                'cond'   => $value['cond']);
            } else {
                $newArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        $this->_data['items'] = $newArray;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery conflict with Prototype in magento:

Simplest solution is to add at the end of your main jquery file.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Or create your custom js file and add this line and also include this file after main js.